# Can not populate zsh autocompletion with simple ls output

Tags: unix, shell, autocomplete, zsh

The problem is that I can't find a way to properly populate `boxes` array. Here's the code:

```
local expl
declare -a boxes
boxes = $(ls $HOME/.vagrant/boxes --color=none)
_wanted boxes expl 'help' compadd $boxes
```

Throws an exception:

```
vagrant help __box_list:13: command not found: boxes
__box_list:13: command not found: boxes
__box_list:13: command not found: boxes
```

ls command works fine if tried manually:

```
ls $HOME/.vagrant/boxes --color=none
lucid32  lucid64
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*zsh* doesn't seem to like the spaces around the `=`.

`boxes=$(ls $HOME/.vagrant/boxes --color=none)` works, which gets us a step further, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved the problem:

```
_wanted application expl 'command' compadd $(command ls -1 $HOME/.vagrant/boxes 2>/dev/null| sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
boxes=($HOME/.vagrant/boxes/*(N:t))
```

- [Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- In shell syntax, you can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment.
- `boxes=(…)` creates an array.
- `(N:t)` retains only the base names of the files matched by the pattern. The parentheses introduce [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87). `N` means that the expansion will be empty if no file matches, and `:` means the next character is a [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC66).